# How should I solve QH6154 qhull precision error?

Tags: error-handling, qhull, mujoco

I am trying to use mujoco compile on 3D object with obj files. When I run the script I get following error. Please let me know if you have any insights.

```
QH6154 qhull precision error: initial facet 1 is coplanar with the interior point
ERRONEOUS FACET:
- f1
    - flags: bottom simplicial flipped
    - normal:         0        0       -1
    - offset:       0.52
    - vertices: p2(v2) p1(v1) p0(v0)
    - neighboring facets: f2 f3 f4

While executing:  | qhull Qt
Options selected for Qhull 2012.1 2012/02/18:
  run-id 1640577472  Qtriangulate  _pre-merge  _zero-centrum  _max-width 1.1
  Error-roundoff 8.5e-16  _one-merge 5.9e-15  _near-inside 3e-14
  Visible-distance 1.7e-15  U-coplanar-distance 1.7e-15  Width-outside 3.4e-15
  _wide-facet 1e-14

precision problems (corrected unless 'Q0' or an error)
      2 flipped facets
      2 degenerate hyperplanes recomputed with gaussian elimination
      4 nearly singular or axis-parallel hyperplanes
      2 zero divisors during back substitute
      3 zero divisors during gaussian elimination

The input to qhull appears to be less than 3 dimensional, or a
computation has overflowed.

Qhull could not construct a clearly convex simplex from points:
- p3(v3):  0.45  0.28  0.52
- p2(v2):  0.45 -0.26  0.52
- p1(v1):  0.45  0.28  0.52
- p0(v0): -0.61 -0.26  0.52

The center point is coplanar with a facet, or a vertex is coplanar
with a neighboring facet.  The maximum round off error for
computing distances is 8.5e-16.  The center point, facets and distances
to the center point are as follows:

center point    0.185     0.01     0.52

facet p2 p1 p0 distance=    0
facet p3 p1 p0 distance= -0.12
facet p3 p2 p0 distance=    0
facet p3 p2 p1 distance= -0.27

These points either have a maximum or minimum x-coordinate, or
they maximize the determinant for k coordinates.  Trial points
are first selected from points that maximize a coordinate.

The min and max coordinates for each dimension are:
  0:     -0.61      0.45  difference= 1.06
  1:     -0.26      0.28  difference= 0.54
  2:      0.52      0.52  difference=    0

If the input should be full dimensional, you have several options that
may determine an initial simplex:
  - use 'QJ'  to joggle the input and make it full dimensional
  - use 'QbB' to scale the points to the unit cube
  - use 'QR0' to randomly rotate the input for different maximum points
  - use 'Qs'  to search all points for the initial simplex
  - use 'En'  to specify a maximum roundoff error less than 8.5e-16.
  - trace execution with 'T3' to see the determinant for each point.

If the input is lower dimensional:
  - use 'QJ' to joggle the input and make it full dimensional
  - use 'Qbk:0Bk:0' to delete coordinate k from the input.  You should
    pick the coordinate with the least range.  The hull will have the
    correct topology.
  - determine the flat containing the points, rotate the points
    into a coordinate plane, and delete the other coordinates.
  - add one or more points to make the input full dimensional.
Error: qhull error
Object name = original-10, id = 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/curious-sapien/datagen/SyntheticArticulatedData/sapien_dataset/dataset_tools.py", line 327, in <module>
    generate_mujoco_scene_xml(urdf_file=args.input_files[0], xml_file=args.output_files[0], obj_type=args.obj_type)
  File "/home/curious-sapien/datagen/SyntheticArticulatedData/sapien_dataset/dataset_tools.py", line 64, in generate_mujoco_scene_xml
    xml_tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1222, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 569, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
```

There was a solution I found, stating that the values should not exceed 3 places after the decimal. I wrote a Python script to truncate all the values to up to 3 decimal places, but I still couldn't get rid of the error. Additionally, I tried using the 'QJ' parameter for qhull, but it didn't solve the problem.

Apologies for the incomplete question as I cannot divulge any more information. I would genuinely appreciate it if someone could provide any insights to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mesh with 0 volume, the error is pretty clear about that.
Flat meshes are not allowed.
Fix your mesh or remove it.